# Power BI Conditional Formatting "Based on Field" List is Empty

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a field of a table in a report in Power BI online.

The report is connected to a dataset that is in MS Teams and continues to function.  All existing conditional formatting is unchanged.

These are the steps I took:

1. Switch report to edit mode
2. Select table
3. Select conditional formatting - advanced controls
4. In the pop-up window, select "Based on Field"

Then, the drop down list is blank and says {{::placeholderText}}.

This can now be recreated in any report, new or existing, where I attempt conditional formatting.

[image: Screen Capture of Issue]

I tried creating a new report from a new dataset, and attempted to add conditional formatting to a table.  The same result happened.

I tried signing out of my Microsoft account and signing back in, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by adding `?conditionalFormattingModern=1` to the url for the online editor like this: `https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/xxx/ReportSection?conditionalFormattingModern=1`. ([source of idea](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Treemap-Conditional-Formatting-Bug/idc-p/2448012#M78123))

I'm not sure if it will work correctly after I publish the visual though. Apparently this [isn't an issue on Power BI Desktop](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Web-Url-Conditional-formatting-placeholderText-instaed-of-list/idi-p/2455148) though- so it's probably fine.

Update: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong- but the conditional formatting doesn't seem to be actually applied. It's just that the editor window displays correctly.